# Decoding long Air Conditioner ir code

Tags: infrared, lirc

I am using Lirc software in Rpi to record raw ir codes, analyse it and save it as conf file. I am further using this conf file in Android App to generate raw code and send it to the ir blaster. This is working perfectly fine in case of TV or music systems. 
But in case of AC, during irrecord, the remote sends the complete information of AC including Temp, fan speed, clock, blow etc. So during record I have to consider all combinations of AC remote options in order to make a conf file. This is very tedious and inefficient method.

I need help to determine the long AC ir signals efficiently and port it to Android App for the further control.

Regards,
Ritika

Comment: Is it a Fujitsu system? [Here's](https://www.remotecentral.com/cgi-bin/mboard/rc-discrete/thread.cgi?4894) a thread where people have decoded it. Look for the PDF someone posted.